# getAttribute method not working in IE but working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I wrote a JavaScript to get the value of the class attribute using get Attribute method. It's working and I satisfied with my requirement in all browsers except IE.

The text area component inserted dynamically in to a jsf page. Whenever onload we execute this JavaScript function to show text editor for text area.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
  function showingRTFTextArea(){
   // alert("before Starting");
    var textareaEle=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
   // alert("Textarea fields:"+textareaEle.toString());
    for(var i=0;i<textareaEle.length;i++){
            var textareaObj=textareaEle[i];
            //alert(textareaObj.getAttribute('Class'));
            if(textareaObj.getAttribute('Class')=='rtfclass'){
                var nameOfEle=textareaObj.getAttribute('name');
                 CKEDITOR.inline(nameOfEle);
               //  alert("set the RTF");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Code please. show us your code..

Comment: Create a Fiddle please - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE try className instead of class.

```
if(textareaObj.getAttribute('className')=='rtfclass')
```

Comment: hi  Marcel Thank u your quick response i tried with "className" . but i am getting null

Comment: Actually this should be `textareaObj.className == ...`.

Comment: Yeh got it Mr marcel. Thank you so much

Comment: A small Query How can we get the name attribute from the component like "object.getAttribute(name)"

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to test for the presence of a CSS class this works in all browsers:

```
if(textareaObj.classList.contains('rtfclass')){
//...
```

}